# Avoiding question mark in string

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, split

How do you avoid a question mark so that it won't be part of a string?

For example: the return value here should be 7 but it returns 6 because it doesn't account for 'soup?'. How would it be possible to avoid the question mark? Any help is appreciated.

```
function timedReading (maxLength, text) {
var sep = text.split(" ");
result = 0;
count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < sep.length; i++) {
  if(sep[i].length<=maxLength) {
    result += sep[i];
    count++;
   }
}
return count;
}
timedReading(4,"The Fox asked the stork, 'How is the soup?'");
```

Comment: You could use string [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace them with empty string.

Comment: Just replace everything that isn't whatever you want with nothing? For instance, alphabet and space -> `str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/,'')`

Answer (score 2):

You can e.g. filter each word from the special characters.

```js
function timedReading(maxLength, text) {
  var sep = text.split(" ");
  result = 0;
  count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sep.length; i++) {
    if (sep[i].split('').filter(v => !/[^A-za-z0-9]/.test(v)).join('').length <= maxLength) {
      result += sep[i];
      count++;
    }
  }
  console.log(count);
}
timedReading(4, "The Fox asked the stork, 'How is the soup?'");
```